# Coherence cache for.net client

Tags: oracle-coherence

I am trying to access a coherence cache using .net client.The cluster is already set up , all I have to do is to access the coherence cache from the client side and get the objects from the cacheservice . As of now I have the coherence dll and the client config .what else should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the 'Developing Remote Clients for Oracle Coherence' guide,
specifically client side configuration:

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHCG/gs_configextend.htm#BEBEGIAE

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did set up everything fine on the client side . All oonifgs are in place(pof, coherence ,app and cache ). The problem I face while tryin to access a particular cache is "Failed to load operational configuration: FileResource(Uri = file://Coherence.xml, AbsolutePath = C:\Documents and Settings\mathialp\Desktop\POC\POC\bin\Debug\Coherence.xml) "

Comment: Add Configuration files and initialization code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The link included in the other answer is a great start. Basically:

1. You run at least one "proxy" in the cluster
2. You configure the client to point to the proxy or proxies (or a load balancer in front of the proxies)
3. You use the Coherence C# API in .NET and it finds the configuration and connects to proxy